# how to deal "+" in asp.net mvc3 routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

my routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Tag",
    "tag/{t}/{action}",
    new { controller = "tag", action = "unsolved" }
    );
```

the link like:

```
<a href="/tag/@(Uri.EscapeDataString(tagName))/unsolved">@tagName</a>
```

if the tagName not contain "+",all work well , else ,like "http://www.test.com/tag/c%2B%2B/unsolved"(%2B come from @(Uri.EscapeDataString("+")),i get the error: HTTP error 404.11 - Not Found

who can help me? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try allowing double escaping in the `<system.webServer>` section of your web.config as I suspect that you are having this problem only in IIS 7 and not in the Visual Studio development server (which by the way you should have mentioned in your question):

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Further reading: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx

Comment: for some reason,i could not modify the web.config,is have other solution?

Comment: @artwl, no. You will have to replace this character with something else in this case. The web server won't allow you using it. Another possibility is to use query string parameters (like `/tags/unsolved?tag=...`) for the tags instead of putting it in the path portion.

Comment: Thx @Darin, I had no idea that there was a difference between IIS and Casini, you just saved me a ton of time.

Answer (score 0):

Your MVC web application generates an link that include any character (%,+,/,etc.). So use URL encode the string and generate link:

```
new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext)
       .RouteUrl("Tag", 
                 new { tagName= HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(tagName) };
```